# Epression with max and multiple condition

Tags: sql, oracle, function, case, rank

I have the below table. I want one value per chapter. (I have SQL with a case expression but is returning incorrectly, so I will not show to avoid confusion.)

Condition PER Chapter:

A - END_DT is NOT NULL AND ROLE = RED AND USERID IS NOT NULL THEN LAST ROW VALUE FOR USERID

B - END_DT is NULL AND ROLE = RED THEN LAST ROW VALUE FOR USERID

TableP

```
END_DT      ROLE   PK    USERID  CHAPTER
 01/10/19    RED   101     5       1
 01/10/19    BLUE  102     5       1
 01/10/19    RED   103     7       1
 01/10/19    RED   104             1
             RED   105     8       2
             BLUE  106     9       2
             BLUE  107     5       3
```

Expected Results:

```
CHAPTER   USERID
 1          7
 2          8
```

Comment: what if the role is BLUE?

Comment: This is incomplete. You want one value per chapter, you say, so why do you also say "LAST ROW VALUE FOR **USERID**"? And if you are talking about "Condition PER Chapter", how can you talk of a certain `END_DT`, `ROLE` and `USERID`? There are various per chapter. Please clarify.

Comment: What does "LAST ROW VALUE" mean for B? When there is no `END_DT`, then there is no *last* row. Or is the `PK` guanranteed to be ascending and you refer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select chapter, userID
from
(
  select top 1 chapter, last_value(userID) over(order by userID desc)as rw, userID
  from sample
  where END_DT is NOT NULL AND ROLE = 'RED' 
  union
  select top 1 chapter, last_value(userID) over(order by userID desc)as rw, userID
  from sample
  where END_DT is NULL AND ROLE = 'RED'
) w
```

Comment: There is no `TOP` keyword in Oracle. And `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` would pick a row arbitrarily. Your query is looking for RED entries picking one with a date and one without, showing the row's user and chapter and the last userid whatever chapter. If both rows happen to show the same data, you remove one with `UNION`. This seems a bit flawed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You want one userid per chapter.
2. You only look at records with role = 'RED' and a userid.
3. Of these you prefer rows with a date. If there are no rows with a date for a chapter, you are fine with a no-date row.
4. Of the selected rows you want to use the one with the highest `PK`.

Use Oracle's `KEEP LAST` for this ranking:

```
select
  chapter,
  max(userid) keep (dense_rank last order by case when end_dt is null then 1 else 2 end, id)
from mytable
where role = 'RED' and userid is not null
group by chapter
order by chapter;
```

Or use `ROW_NUMBER`, if you want a standard SQL query:

```
select chapter, userid
from
(
  select
    chapter,
    userid,
    row_number() over (partition by chapter 
                       order by case when end_dt is null then 2 else 1 end,
                                id desc) as rn
  from mytable
  where role = 'RED' and userid is not null
)
where rn = 1
order by chapter;
```